# Combine two SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    party.name, leger.partyId, leger.descriptions, leger.cashBySum, 
    leger.cashByName, leger.date 
FROM  
    leger 
INNER JOIN 
    party ON leger.partyId = party.id 
WHERE 
    (leger.partyId = @partyID) 
    AND (CAST(leger.date AS date) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate) 
ORDER BY 
    leger.date 
CROSS JOIN 
    SELECT 
        (CASE WHEN (SUM(cashBySum) > SUM(cashByName)) THEN N'جمع' 
              WHEN (SUM(cashBySum) < SUM(cashByName)) THEN N' بنام' 
              ELSE '' END) AS balancetype, 
        SUM(cashBySum) - SUM(cashByName) AS balance, 
        ABS(SUM(cashBySum) - SUM(cashByName)) AS blc
    FROM leger
    WHERE (partyId = @partyTypes) AND (date < @fromdate)
```

How can I combine this query to a single query and use in an RDLC report?

I want to get the last balance and then calculate the balance on date by subtracting the last balance to make the report.

Comment: Are you looking for `union` rather than `cross join`? If so then you'll also have to move `order by` to the end of the query.

Comment: i use both Union but not working

Comment: Put a sample result table, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the queries horizontally with a cross join. Perhaps this is what you mean?

```
WITH q1 as (
    SELECT
        party.name, leger.partyId, leger.descriptions,
        leger.cashBySum, leger.cashByName, leger.date
    FROM
        leger INNER JOIN party ON leger.partyId = party.id
    WHERE
        leger.partyId = @partyID AND CAST(leger.date AS date) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
), q2 as (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(cashBySum) > SUM(cashByName) THEN N'جمع' 
            WHEN SUM(cashBySum) < SUM(cashByName) THEN N' بنام'
            ELSE ''
        END AS balancetype,
        SUM(cashBySum) - SUM(cashByName) AS balance,
        ABS(SUM(cashBySum) - SUM(cashByName)) AS blc
    FROM leger
    WHERE partyId = @partyTypes AND date < @fromdate
)
SELECT q1.*, q2.*
FROM q1 CROSS JOIN q2
ORDER BY leger.date
```

Using an `ORDER BY` suggests that you have multiple rows in at least the first query. The second is aggregated into a single group so it should be a single row as I'm anticipating; however, if the second somehow has more than one row also then in that case I'm not sure that a cross join is really what you want.

A union would require you to match up the number and types on the columns between the two queries. That's probably why it wasn't working for you.

Comment: The second is all aggregate so it should be one row.  It is just strange they want to repeat that data.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't actually been paying much attention to the output as I wrote that.

Comment: how we stop to repeat that data

Comment: If you only want the data to appear once you could suppress it on the reporting side. In fact you might want to use two different queries and two different tables in that case which would eliminate the need for this question entirely.

Comment: @manshaali But repeat data is exactly what you asked for.  You asked to combine those two queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    party.name, leger.partyId, leger.descriptions, leger.cashBySum, 
    leger.cashByName, leger.date 
FROM  
    leger 
INNER JOIN 
    party ON leger.partyId = party.id 
          AND  leger.partyId = @partyID 
          AND (CAST(leger.date AS date) BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate) 

CROSS JOIN 
  ( SELECT 
        (CASE WHEN (SUM(cashBySum) > SUM(cashByName)) THEN N'جمع' 
              WHEN (SUM(cashBySum) < SUM(cashByName)) THEN N' بنام' 
              ELSE '' END) AS balancetype, 
        SUM(cashBySum) - SUM(cashByName) AS balance, 
        ABS(SUM(cashBySum) - SUM(cashByName)) AS blc
    FROM leger
    WHERE (partyId = @partyTypes) AND (date < @fromdate) 
  )
ORDER BY 
    leger.date
```